# How do i add and subtract values from checkboxes and select option dropdowns in an input text field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

please view what i have

```
$("#checkbox").change(function() {
if ($('input#checkbox').is(':checked')) {
var checkvalue = +$(this).val(),
$boxInput = $('input[name="box"]');
$boxInput.val(+$boxInput.val() + checkvalue);
} else {
var checkvalue = +$(this).val(),
$boxInput = $('input[name="box"]');
$boxInput.val(+$boxInput.val() - checkvalue);
}
});

$("#numbers").change(function() {
var firstdropvalue = +$(this).val(),
$boxInput = $('input[name="box"]');
$boxInput.val(+$boxInput.val() + firstdropvalue);
});

$("#morenumbers").change(function() {
var seconddropvalue = +$(this).val(),
$boxInput = $('input[name="box"]');
$boxInput.val(+$boxInput.val() + seconddropvalue);
});
```

demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/nZ9J8/1/

i want to update an input text box value from multiple dropdowns and a checkbox.

first, i don't want it to keep adding and adding each time a different dropdown selection is made.

here is breakdown...

checkbox = 0 when unchecked, 2 when checked

dropdown one has 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4

dropdown two has 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4

input text box should be checkbox + dropdown one + dropdown two

if checkbox is checked and 2 is selected in both dropdowns then it's 2 + 2 + 2 which should make text field 6.

if checkbox is unchecked and 1 is selected in dropdown one and 3 is selected in dropdown two then it's 0 + 1 + 3 which should make text field 4.

the trick is if a person changes their mind and changes the checkbox or dropdowns, the text field should update accordingly going up or down as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. http://jsfiddle.net/BxSU6/19/

```
function calculate(){
    var checkVal = ($('input#checkbox').is(':checked')) ? $('input#checkbox').val() : 0;
    var sum = parseIntX($("#numbers").val()) + parseIntX($("#morenumbers").val()) + parseIntX(checkVal);

    $('#box').val(sum);
}

function parseIntX(num){
    return (isNaN(parseInt(num))) ? 0 : parseInt(num);
}

$("#numbers, #morenumbers, #checkbox").change(function() {
    calculate();
});`
```

Comment: not sure what you did there.  the 2 dropdowns do correct calculations only if checkbox is checked?  the dropdowns should do that on their own.  the checkbox is a separate and independent calculation.

Comment: i think i see now.  when checked the dropdowns add.  when unchecked they subtract.  that's not what i was going for.  the 2 dropdowns should always add whether the checkbox is checked or unchecked, however, the sum in the text field should go up and down depending on what is selected or checked or unchecked.

Comment: thanks, seems to good, but when i use it in my real application and i use numbers such as 0.390, the resulting sum is 0.  do you know why and if there is a fix?

Comment: @leoarce If you want decimal numbers to work use `parseFloat(num);` instead of `parseInt(num);`

Comment: just out of curiosity, if i get a sum of this: 2.4299999999999997, how can i keep it to 3 max decimal places?  like this: 2.430 or 2.429 (doesn't matter if it rounds up or not but rounding is better)

Comment: fixed it like this: $('#box').val(sum.toFixed(3));